# How does redis sharding work when cluster mode is enabled

Tags: redis

I'm trying to understand if I have a dataset that has some string keys like
data1
data2 
and so on
how does sharding work if I have cluster mode enabled? Say I have 6 shards, how does it decide data1 has to go to shard 1, data 2 to shard 2 and so on?

Comment: Read the docs, specifically https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-distribution-model

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, you can find all the information related to clustering in here: [Overview of Redis Cluster main components](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-distribution-model)

I'm leaving the key concepts/summaries here:
All the keys are converted to a hashed numeric value(range between **0 to 16384**). Then each node assigns a range of hash_values to serve.

> Say I have 6 shards, how does it decide data1 has to go to shard 1, data 2 to shard 2 and so on?

**Ans:** So when you have cluster mode enabled, each of your cluster nodes will serve a range of keys.while the cluster is stable each node will store approximately 16384/6 = 2731 hased_values of keys. Now hash will be calculated using following rules: for key `data1`:

`hash_slot = Hash_Algorithm(data1) % 16384`
Hash algorithm could be MD5, CRC etc.

> `hash_slot = CRC16(data1) % 16384`

Run this command on redis-cli to know which have what range:  [***`$> cluster slots`***](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-slots)

**Sample Output (new version, includes IDs):**

```
127.0.0.1:30001> cluster slots
1) 1) (integer) 0     // begin slot
   2) (integer) 5460  // end slot
   3) 1) "127.0.0.1"
      2) (integer) 30001
      3) "09dbe9720cda62f7865eabc5fd8857c5d2678366"
   4) 1) "127.0.0.1"
      2) (integer) 30004
      3) "821d8ca00d7ccf931ed3ffc7e3db0599d2271abf"
2) 1) (integer) 5461  // begin slot
   2) (integer) 10922 // end slot
   3) 1) "127.0.0.1"
      2) (integer) 30002
      3) "c9d93d9f2c0c524ff34cc11838c2003d8c29e013"
   4) 1) "127.0.0.1"
      2) (integer) 30005
      3) "faadb3eb99009de4ab72ad6b6ed87634c7ee410f"
.....
.....
```

As docs describe:

> ***Keys distribution model***
>
> The key space is split into 16384 slots, effectively setting an upper limit for the cluster size of 16384 master nodes (however the suggested max size of nodes is in the order of ~ 1000 nodes).
>
> Each master node in a cluster handles a subset of the 16384 hash slots. The cluster is stable when there is no cluster reconfiguration in progress (i.e. where hash slots are being moved from one node to another). When the cluster is stable, a single hash slot will be served by a single node (however the serving node can have one or more slaves that will replace it in the case of net splits or failures, and that can be used in order to scale read operations where reading stale data is acceptable).
>
> The base algorithm used to map keys to hash slots is the following (read the next paragraph for the hash tag exception to this rule):
>
> **`HASH_SLOT = CRC16(key) mod 16384`**